# Improving iScroll performance on a large table

Tags: javascript, jquery, iscroll

I'm updating a table header and its first column positions programatically based on how the user scrolls around to keep them aligned.

The issue I'm experiencing is that as soon as my data sets gets big enough, the scrolling gets more and more choppy/less smooth.

The relevant code is at the very bottom of the fiddle:

```
iScroll.on('scroll', function(){
    var pos = $('#scroller').position();
    $('#pos').text('pos.left=' + pos.left + ' pos.top=' + pos.top);

    // code to hold first row and first column
    $('#scroller th:nth-child(1)').css({top: (-pos.top), left: (-pos.left), position:'relative'});
    $('#scroller th:nth-child(n+1)').css({top: (-pos.top), position:'relative'});

    // this seems to be the most expensive operation:
    $('#scroller td:nth-child(1)').css({left: (-pos.left), position:'relative'});
});
```

I know that this can be written a lot more efficent by caching the elements and so on. For example, I have tried saving the elements in to an array and updating their position in a more "vanilla" fashion:

```
headerElements[i].style.left = left + 'px'; // etc...
```

No matter how fast I make the callback, I'm still not happy about the result. Do you have any suggestions?

https://jsfiddle.net/0qv1kjac/16/

Comment: Is it 100% necessary that you use a tool to create a scroller?

Comment: You can create an array that contains your html in chunks. Load each index of the array based on current scroll position, assuming pos is a positive value to previous position. What this should do, is load a chunks worth of data(say 100 rows), and will not load data until you reach the next 'checkpoint'. hth!

Answer (score 6):

Just use [ClusterizeJS](https://clusterize.js.org/)! It can handle hundreds of thousands of rows and was built *exactly* for this purpose.

How does it work, you ask?

> The main idea is not to pollute DOM with all used tags. Instead of that - it splits the list to clusters, then shows elements for current scroll position and adds extra rows to top and bottom of the list to emulate full height of table so that browser shows scrollbar as for full list

Answer (score 4):

To be able to handle big amounts of data you need data virtualization. It has some restrictions, though.

First you need to decide the size of a view port. Let's say you want to render 10 items in a row and 20 items in column. It would be 10x20 items then. In you fiddle it's div with id wrapper.

Then you need to know total amount of data you have. From your fiddle it would be 100x100 items. And, also you need to know height and width of a item (cell). Let's take 40x120 (in px).

So **div#wrapper** is a view port, it should have fixed sized like 10x20 items. Then you need to set up correct width and height for **table**. The height of **table** would be equal to total amount of data in column including head by item height. Width for **table** would be total amount of items in single row by item width.

Once you set up these, **div#wrapper** will receive horizontal and vertical scrolls. Now you able to scroll left and bottom, but it will be just empty space. However this empty space is able to hold exact amount of data you have.

Then you need to take scroll data left and top (position), which comes in pixels and normalize it to amount of items, so you could know not how many pixels you've scrolled, but how many items you've scrolled(or rows if we scroll from top to bottom).

It could be done by division of pixels scrolled on item height. For example, you scrolled to left by 80px, that's 2 items. It means these items should be invisible because you've scrolled past them. So you know that you scrolled past 2 items, and you know that you should see 10 items in a row. That means you take your data array which has data for row with 100 items, and slice it like this:

```
var visibleItems = rowData.slice(itemsScrolled, itemsScrolled + 10);
```

It will give you items which should be visible in viewport at current scroll position. Once you have these items you need to construct html and append it to table.

Also on each scroll event you need to set top and left position for **tbody and thead** so they would move with scroll, otherwise you will have your data, but it will be at (0; 0) inside a viewport.

Anyway, code speaks thousand of words, so here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Ldfjrg81/9/

**Note**, that this approach requires heights and widths to be precise, otherwise it will work incorrectly. Also if you have items of different sizes, this also should be taken into consideration, so better if you have fixed and equal sizes of items. In jsfiddle, I commented out the code which forces first column to stay in place, but you can render it separately.

It's a good solution to stick to some library as suggested in comments, since it handles a lot of cases for you.

You can make rendering even faster if use react.js or vue.js

Answer (score 3):

This won't be the answer your are looking for but here's my 2 cents anyway.

Javascript animation (especially given the amount that the DOM has to render) will never be as smooth as you want it. Even if you could get it smooth on your machine, chances are that it will vary drastically on other peoples (Older PC's, Browsers etc).

I would see 2 options if I were to tackle this myself.

1. Go old school and add a horizontal and vertical scrollbar. I know it's not a pretty solution but it would work well.
2. Only render a certain amount of rows and discard those off screen. This could be a bit complicated but in essence you would render say 10 rows. Once the user scrolls to a point where the 11th should be there, render that one and remove the 1st. You would pop them in and out as needed.

In terms of the actual JS (you mentioned putting elements in to an array), that isn't going to help. The actual choppyness is due to the browser needing to render that many elements in the first place.

Comment: To get a practical approach: Regarding the 2nd option mentioned, it may be worth taking a look into Clusterize.js (https://clusterize.js.org/) which does the job of rendering only parts of a list for you.

Comment: "In terms of the actual JS (you mentioned putting elements in to an array), that isn't going to help.": The point here is that the DOM API is faster than going through jQuery. I should have mentioned that speeding this up in the latest Chrome is enough for me. Even if I go with "1.", I would still have to reposition the header and first column as I do today. 2 is a viable option, though I'm still intrested if the code above can be optimized in such a way that it's not necessary, thus the bounty :)

Comment: Changing the JS would (probably) have minimal effect since it seems to be more of a graphical rendering issue. I would have a look in to the cluster approach mentioned, it seems the more logical approach

Comment: If you have tried updating the position of the elements using native JS then I can't see any other way to speed things up in that respect.

Answer (score 2):

You're experiencing choppy / non-smooth scrolling because the `scroll` event fires at a **very high pace**.

And **every time it fires** you're adjusting the position of **many elements**: this is expensive and furthermore until the browser has completed the repaint it's **unresponsive** (here the choppy scrolling).

**I see two options:**

**Option number one:** display only the visible subset of the whole data set (this has been already suggested in another answer so I won't go futher)

---

**Option number two (easier)**

First, let animations on `left` and `top` css changes occurr via **transitions**. This is more efficient, is non-blocking and often let the browser take advantage of the **gpu**

Then instead of repeteadly adjust `left` and `top`, do it once a while; for example 0.5 seconds. This is done by the function `ScrollWorker()` (see code below) that recalls itself via a `setTimeout()`.

Finally use the callback invoked by the scroll event to keep the `#scroller` position (stored in a variable) updated.

```
// Position of the `#scroller` element
// (I used two globals that may pollute the global namespace
// that piece of code is just for explanation purpose)    

var oldPosition, 
    newPosition;


// Use transition to perform animations
// You may set this in the stylesheet

$('th').css( { 'transition': 'left 0.5s, top 0.5s' } );
$('td').css( { 'transition': 'left 0.5s, top 0.5s' } );


// Save the initial position

newPosition = $('#scroller').position();
oldPosition = $('#scroller').position();


// Upon scroll just set the position value

iScroll.on('scroll', function() {
    newPosition = $('#scroller').position();
} );


// Start the scroll worker

ScrollWorker();


function ScrollWorker() { 

    // Adjust the layout if position changed (your original code)

    if( newPosition.left != oldPosition.left || newPosition.top != oldPosition.top ) {
        $('#scroller th:nth-child(1)').css({top: (-newPosition.top), left: (-newPosition.left), position:'relative'});
        $('#scroller th:nth-child(n+1)').css({top: (-newPosition.top), position:'relative'});
        $('#scroller td:nth-child(1)').css({left: (-newPosition.left), position:'relative'});

        // Update the stored position

        oldPosition.left = newPosition.left;
        oldPosition.top  = newPosition.top;

        // Let animation complete then check again
        // You may adjust the timer value
        // The timer value must be higher or equal the transition time

        setTimeout( ScrollWorker, 500 );

    } else {

        // No changes
        // Check again after just 0.1secs

        setTimeout( ScrollWorker, 100 );
    }
}
```

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lm4uj6zg/)

I set the **Worker** pace and the **transition** time to **0.5 secs**. You may adjust the value with higher or lower timing, eventually in a dinamic way based on the number of elements in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Here are some improvements to the code from your JS Fiddle. You can view my edits at: https://jsfiddle.net/briankueck/u63maywa/

Some suggested improvements are:

1. Switching `position:relative` values in the JS layer to `position:fixed` in the CSS layer.
2. Shortening the jQuery DOM chains, so that the code doesn't start at the root element & walk all the way through the dom with each $ lookup. The scroller is now the root element. Everything uses `.find()` off of that element, which creates shorter trees & jQuery can traverse those branches faster.
3. Moving the logging code out of the DOM & into the console.log. I've added a debugging switch to disable it, as you're looking for the fastest scrolling on the table. If it runs fast enough for you, then you can always re-enable it to see it in the JSFiddle. If you really need to see that on the iPhone, then it can be added into the DOM. Although, it's probably not necessary to see the left & top position values in the iPhone.
4. Remove all extraneous $ values, which aren't mapped to the jQuery object. Something like $scroller gets confusing with $, as the latter is the jQuery library, but the former isn't.
5. Switching to ES6 syntax, by using `let` instead of `var` will make your code look more modern.
6. There is a new left calculation in the `<th>` tag, which you'll want to look at.
7. The iScroll event listener has been cleaned up. With `position:fixed`, the top `<th>` tags only need to have the `top` property applied to them. The left `<td>` tags only need to have the `left` property applied to them. The corner `<th>` needs to have both the `top` & `left` property applied to it.
8. Remove everything that's unnecessary, like the extraneous HTML tags which were used for logging purposes.
9. If you really want to go more vanilla, change out the `.css()` methods for the actual `.style.left= -pos.left + 'px';` and `.style.top= -pos.top + 'px';` properties in the JS code.

Try using a diff tool like [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org) or [Beyond Compare](http://scootersoftware.com/) to compare the code from your version to what's in my edits, so that you can easily see the differences.

Hopefully, this will make the scrolling smoother, as the scroll event doesn't have to process anything that it doesn't need to do... like 5 full DOM traversing look-ups, rather than 3 short-tree searches.

Enjoy! :)

**HTML:**

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <table id="scroller">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* ... only the relevant bits ... */

thead th {
  background-color: #99a;
  min-width: 120px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  position: fixed; /* New */
  z-index: 9;
}

thead th:nth-child(1) {/*first cell in the header*/
  border-left: 1px solid #222; /* New: Border fix */
  border-right: 2px solid #222; /* New: Border fix */
  position: fixed; /* New */
  display: block; /*seperates the first cell in the header from the header*/
  background-color: #88b;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

**JS:**

```
// main code
let debug = false;

$(function(){ 
  let scroller = $('#scroller');
  let top = $('<tr/>');
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    let left = (i === 0) ? 0 : 1;
    top.append('<th style="left:' + ((123*i)+left) + 'px;">'+ Math.random().toString(36).substring(7) +'</th>');
  }
  scroller.find('thead').append(top);
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    let row = $('<tr/>');
    for (let j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
      row.append('<td>'+ Math.random().toString(36).substring(7) +'</td>');
    }
    scroller.find('tbody').append(row);
  }

  if (debug) console.log('initialize iscroll');
  let iScroll = null;
  try {
    iScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', { 
      interactiveScrollbars: true, 
      scrollbars: true, 
      scrollX: true, 
      probeType: 3, 
      useTransition:false, 
      bounce:false
    });
  } catch(e) {
    if (debug) console.error(e.name + ":" + e.message + "\n" + e.stack);
  }

  if (debug) console.log('initialized');

  iScroll.on('scroll', function(){
    let pos = scroller.position();
    if (debug) console.log('pos.left=' + pos.left + ' pos.top=' + pos.top);

    // code to hold first row and first column
    scroller.find('th').css({top:-pos.top}); // Top Row
    scroller.find('th:nth-child(1)').css({left:-pos.left}); // Corner
    scroller.find('td:nth-child(1)').css({left:-pos.left}); // 1st Left Column
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Some good suggestions, though I'm not really noticing any performance improvements.

Comment: You could also try getting away from jQuery's code & using native JS calls, whenever possible. For example: `$('#scroller');` would become `document.getElementById('scroller');` To boost the scrolling's smoothness, you'd need to rewrite all of the scroller.find() methods into native JS. You can also use the .style.left and .style.top properties in JS to avoid using jQuery's `.css()` methods. It sounds like converting just the 5 non-debugging lines in the `iScroll.on('scroll', function(){` event listener would give you the best performance boost.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I tried already. And it does help :) I was looking for some other ways to improve it, but I guess aiming for a more paginated approach is better...

Comment: It seems like you're heading into what is called infinite scrolling. Years ago (in 2006) I had to build an infinite scrollbar which could handle 10,000+ email rows. To pull that off (without using a library), try using the .splice() method on the data rows array for the DOM. The idea is to maintain a 2nd array in the JS layer (the model) & then only render to the 1st array what fits inside of the viewport plus & minus a buffer of rows. The top & bottom buffers act as triggers, which allow for more data to be spliced in & the buffered data to be Ajax loaded. Use native JS for the fastest speed.

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary that you create your own scroller? Why don't you just style the data in HTML/CSS and just use the `overflow` attribute? JavaScript needs work on it's ability to adjust framerates. I was using your jFiddle earlier and it worked just fine with the native overflow handler.

Answer (score 0):

Found this in the manual. Probably not what you wanna hear but it's the way it is:

IScroll is a class that needs to be initiated for each scrolling area. There's no limit to the number of iScrolls you can have in each page if not that imposed by the device CPU/Memory.
Try to keep the DOM as simple as possible. iScroll uses the hardware compositing layer but there's a limit to the elements the hardware can handle.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the performance degradation is happening is that your scroll event handler is firing again and again and again instead of waiting for a reasonable and imperceptible interval.

[image: invocations of scroll event handler]

The screenshot shows what happened when I tracked how many times the event handler fired, while scrolling for just a few seconds. The computationally-heavy event handler was fired over 600 times!!! This is more than 60 times per second!!!

It may seem counter-intuitive, but reducing the frequency that the table is updated will vastly increase perceived response times. If your user scrolls for fraction of a second, about 150 milliseconds, and the table is updated ten times, freezing the display during the scrolling, the net result is far worse than if the table were updated only three times and moved fluidly rather than freezing. It is just wasted processor burn to update more times than the browser can handle without freezing.

So, how do you make an event handler that fires at a maximum frequency, for example 25 times per second, even it is triggered much more often, like 100 times per second?

The naive way of doing it is to run a setInterval event. That is better, but horribly inefficient as well. There is a better way of doing it, by setting a delayed event handler, and clearing it on subsequent invocations before setting it again, until the minimum time interval has passed. This way it only runs no more often than at the maximum desired frequency. This is one major case for why the ``clearInterval'' method was invented.

Here is live working code:

https://jsfiddle.net/pgjvf7pb/7/

Note: when refreshing continuously like this, the header column may appear out of position.

I advise to do the update only when the scrolling has paused for about 25ms or so, rather than continuously. This way, it appears to the user that the header column is dynamically calculated as well as being fixed in place, because it appears instantly after scrolling rather than seeming to scroll with the data.

https://jsfiddle.net/5vcqv7nq/2/

The logic is like this:

*variables outside your event handler*

```
  // stores the scrolling operation for a tiny delay to prevent redundancy
  var fresh;

  // stores time of last scrolling refresh
  var lastfresh = new Date();
```

*operations inside your event handler*

```
  // clears redundant scrolling operations before they are applied
  if (fresh) clearTimeout(fresh);

  var x = function() {
    // stores new time of scrolling refresh
    lastfresh = new Date();
    // perform scrolling update operations here...
  };

  // refresh instantly if it is more than 50ms out of date
  if (new Date() - lastfresh > 50) x();

  // otherwise, pause for half of that time to avoid wasted runs
  else fresh = setTimeout(x, 25);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/pgjvf7pb/7/

Once again, I recommend that you remove the line of code that refreshes the data instantly, and the else condition after that, and simply use one line

```
 fresh = setTimeout(x, 25);
```

This will appear to instantly calculate the header column the moment any scrolling is finished, and saves even more operations. My second link to JS Fiddle shows what this looks like, here: https://jsfiddle.net/5vcqv7nq/2/